# How to stop eclipse to add space between class and ... like template<class ... Args>?

Tags: c++, eclipse, coding-style, ide, variadic-templates

I'm new to eclipse CDT, and I like it. However, there is an annoying thing:

I want my code to look like:

```
template<class... Args>
void f(const Args&... args)
{}
```

rather than look like:

```
template<class ... Args>
void f(const Args&... args)
{}
```

The latter is generated by the eclipse formatter. How to stop it?